# IP whitelisting for calls from Azure DevOps Service hooks

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am looking for the list of IP addresses that can be whitelisted in our Firewalls for inbound calls from the Azure DevOps service. I see it has been asked a couple of times in Stack but no response, did anyone figure it out yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be better off installing an agent locally, this will handle the communications with DevOps.  Just create a new agent pool, and install the agent software (in the pool, just click the "new agent" button for instructions) on an on-prem machine.

If necessary, in your build just create a new agent job that runs on your new pool (to avoid the whole build running on it).

Comment: I want to whitelist the calls from Azure DevOps to our Jenkins instance. So, when the Web hook is fired from the Azure DevOps to trigger a job in Jenkins, it can make through our firewall.

Comment: Sorry, updated my answer as I misunderstood the question.

Comment: I ended up setting up GIT polling on Jenkins for now, which works well. Unfortunately, this may become a problem when we scale up. So, need to figure out a different method to alleviate security concern, and fire the web hooks.